# Accesing Win32 API from FlasCC (aka Crossbridge)

Tags: c++, flash, winapi, cygwin, flascc

I have to compile a C++ project using FlasCC to create a swf. I am able to compile all the CPP files except those that uses Win32 API *("Windows.h", DirectX,etc)*. I have seen the api libraries on the cygwin folder */usr/include/w32api* but not on FlasCC sdk folder. How can I link them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Flascc uses FreeBSD API so nothing windows specific can be used at all unless you write it. And even the libc provided is somewhat limited and lot of the API is dummy. Most of the IO and system dependent code needs to be rewritten to be used with flascc.